# Possible to hide admin toolbar for testing display

Tags: users, uri, toolbar

I've worked on and off with Drupal for a few years.

One thing that has bothered me a bit, is that the admin toolbar at the top doesn't give you the full flavour of what the public will see.

I usually get around this by using a second browser where I'm not logged in.

I wonder if there is a simple url parameter or some other setting that can turn off or hide the toolbar for testing display.

searching the web reveals a trick with some permissions.

https://kitt.hodsden.org/blog/2011/02/turning_drupal_7_admin_toolbar

But using a second browser seems easier as I'll want this for just a few minutes at a time.

Could I write a simple plugin that will catch some url parameter and hide the admin toolbar, is there such a thing already?

Answer (score 3):

If your using the built in D7 tool bar, take a look at [Toolbar Hider](https://www.drupal.org/project/toolbar_hide).

> This module will hide/show the toolbar with the press of a key that
>   you configure. It will optionally adjust the page padding to hide the
>   white space. You can also configure if you would like to hide the
>   toolbar by default.

If your using the contributed [admin menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_menu), there is also [Admin Menu Hider](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_menu_dropdown), which does the same thing, but is in alpha.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Masquerade](https://www.drupal.org/project/masquerade) and create user without the permission to use the toolbar.